# Trying to determine the best way to enforce a strict TypeScript null check for function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a TypeScript utility function I've written that takes an Item object in an array, and appends a *quantity* property that increases by 1 for every duplicate Item of that kind that is added to that array.

The problem I'm running into is that I'm already using the spread operator within the function and I'm still getting the TypeScript error stating `Object is possibly undefined`.

I'm not sure how to get around this without writing something verbose to check  `if cartItem && (...rest of my function)`

**EDIT: Version of TypeScript in my project is 3.9.7**

`Current Function`

```
import { Item } from "../../pages/shop/shop.component";

export const addItemToCart = (cartItems: Item[], cartItemToAdd: Item) => {
  const existingCartItem = cartItems.find(
    (cartItem: Item) => cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
  );

  if (existingCartItem) {
    return cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
      cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
        // Error on this line at ? {...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1}
        ?  { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1 }
        : cartItem
    );
  }

  return [...cartItems, { ...cartItemToAdd, quantity: 1 }];
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure where your error is?

Comment: @tmhao2005 Hey just updated the comment in the Code Snippet detailing where the error is

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Honestly I can't see any typing error in above function :)

Comment: Maybe it depends on ts version? Because it [shouldn't throw that error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA9gRlAvFA3gMxjAXFAdgVwFs4IAnAXwG4AoagYxlwGdgo4BDUpKACk9JwBBUqXYgAPPAB8ASiRTU1KMqj8AdIXZgeAS2ARC8xSpNQGzVgmQolpu2od6DAGlt2TcTzieE1GGFAA1FAAjG6m5OEmpBDA+KS4bDQm5DLU5EA)

Comment: @MoshFeu yeah could be, the version I'm running in my project is 3.9.7

Comment: Weird. The playground uses 3.9.2 and it's ok. Try to reproduce it in a playground. Maybe it will be easier to find out what's the issue.